# Are models of ZFC extensional

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm reading *Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide* by Peter Smith (can be downloaded [here](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/)). I came across the following sentence (pg. 17) and can't understand what Smith means:

> (b) Turning to semantics: the first key idea we need is that of a model structure, a (non-empty) domain of objects equipped with some properties, relations and/or functions. And here we treat properties etc. extensionally. In other words, we can think of a property as a set of objects from the domain, a binary relation as a set of pairs from the domain, and so on. (Compare our remarks on naive set theory in §2.1.)

From my limited (informal) knowledge of model theory I've observed from elsewhere, what I envision is that you could take, for example, real numbers and map them to Dedekind cuts and take addition and multiplication and map them to functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (extensionally).

The first thing I'm noting about this:

1. We use ZFC to describe the semantics of something like the real numbers (again, this is my guess from what I've seen about model theory elsewhere)
2. How can we make a model of ZFC? Surely it can't be extensional (such as when talking about $\mathbb{R}$) - there is no "set of all functions" in ZFC. Besides, wouldn't every object (set) in the domain of discourse just get interpreted as itself?

Is model theory ever used when talking about models of ZFC? What would it even mean to have a model of ZFC itself?

Just throwing this out here (I'm obviously very naive). Could someone shed some light?

Comment: You can talk about models of ZFC just like for any other theory. There is, of course, no set of all sets within a given model of ZFC, but it could exist *outside*. Sometime though, you might want to consider a model of ZFC that’s too large to be a set even outside. In that case you can still consider classes and consider a model which has an underlying class instead of set. The collection of all sets does not form a set, but they still form a class, after all. (Though that does require you to use something like NBG for your metatheory instead of ZFC.)

Comment: The main thing here is to distinguish between *theory* and *metatheory*. When you want to study the model theory of ZFC, the theory you’re trying to study and the metatheory you’re using can be the same, so it can be confusing. But you should think of these as two different “copies” of ZFC. Once you do that, there is no real difference between ZFC and any other theory.

Comment: Also, using model theory to study models of ZFC is, in fact, an active area of research. Most of the results stating certain statements are independent of ZFC come from this.

Comment: @David: The last comment is very misleading. There isn't a lot of model theoretic tools used in Independence results in set theory. Both forcing and inner models are decidedly set theoretic (and almost specifically so) and very much not model theoretic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suppose it might be more accurate to say using *concepts* rather than tools from model theory is important in the study of set theory, yeah. Then again, it’s not like model theoretic results are completely irrelevant. Löwenheim-Skolem, for example, is needed for forcing.

Comment: @DavidGao: To an extent, yes, but it is the only tool that is being used, and even that tool is not *really* needed for the majority of forcing arguments. Forcing can be formalised "over the universe" or by simply starting with a CTM which we got axiomatically by positing its existence. The concepts in model theory are usually not very good at dealing with ZFC because either they produce non-standard model, and usually ones that are elementarily equivalent to the original (so independence results cannot be obtained this way), or they are using classification theory [...]

Comment: [...] and in that case ZFC is a "very wild theory" so the modern concepts in model theory which study different models and such, will often not work for it. Not to mention that many of the modern concepts deal with complete theories to begin with, which ZFC is notoriously not.